# Wordpress, is_page parent & child

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to create an is_page statement which targets the parent page & also all of the child pages? This is my code so far.. and only works on the parent page.

```
<?php if( is_page( array( 'view-by-collections') )   ) { ?> 
** MY CODE **
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the ID of the page in question and try something like this:

```
<?php if (is_page(ID_OF_VIEW_BY_COLLECTIONS) || $post->post_parent == ID_OF_VIEW_BY_COLLECTIONS) { ?>
** Your Code **
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This seems to be working for the parent only. I did a bit of research and other people mentioned that a similar solution stopped working at some point. Considering the thread is 7 years old it probably started working again, but now it is not working for me.

Comment: Try using global $post; and change is_page(ID_OF_VIEW_BY_COLLECTIONS) to $post->ID == ID_OF_VIEW_BY_COLLECTIONS